# Adding orIgnore() to relation query builder in TypeORM

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I have a use case for adding entities to a many-to-many relation and ignoring when a duplicate entry is added.

I currently handle it like:

```js
    try {
      await getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .relation(StoryEntity, 'users')
        .of(storyId)
        .add(userId);
    } catch (e) {
      const { code } = e;
      if (code !== 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
        throw new BadRequestException('An unknown error occurred. Please try again.', e);
      }
    }
```

When TypeORM logging is on, I still get the query error stacktrace, so I'd prefer to handle it as I would in the `InsertQueryBuilder` with a call to `.orIgnore()`.  Is this possible with many-to-many relations in TypeORM?

Comment: did you find a solution to that?

Comment: @HRK44 sorry for the very late response.  Aside from the code in my question, I did not find a different/better solution to this.